# Typescript: return type of the child class from method

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I have a Model class and 2 child classes who extends from Model, like this:

**Base Model module:**

```js
/**
 * 
 *  Provider: Model
 *  @module providers/core/utils/model
 *  
 *  @description provides an easy to handle sequelize model
 * 
 */
import { Model as SequelizeModel, InitOptions, ModelAttributes } from 'sequelize'
import sequelize from '@core/libs/sequelize'


export default
    /**
     * 
     *  @class Model @extends SequelizeModel
     *  @description provides a more simply layer to use models
     * 
     */
    class Model extends SequelizeModel {

        /**
         *  @default options
         */
        public static options: InitOptions = {
            sequelize,
            timestamps: true
        }

        /**
         *  @custom options
         */
        public static $options: object = {}

        /**
         *  @model definition
         */
        public static attributes: ModelAttributes = {}


        /**
         *  @init the model
         */
        public static init (): SequelizeModel { // instead of return SequelizeModel I need to return the class who calls itself... (this)

            // here just call init and not return yet
            return super.init.call( this, this.attributes, {
                ...this.options,
                ...this.$options
            })

            // and add here return this
        }

    }
;
```

**Classes that extends from Model:**

```
/**
 *
 *  Model: User
 *  @module app/models/user
 * 
 *  @description basic user model
 * 
 */
import { Model } from '@bananasplit-js' // this is the Model above
import { DataTypes, ModelAttributes } from 'sequelize'


class User extends Model {

    /**
     *  @fields
     */
    public id!: number
    public name!: string
    public lastname!: string
    public email!: string
    public password!: string


    /**
     *  @model
     */
    public static attributes: ModelAttributes = {

        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            autoIncrement: true,
            
            primaryKey: true
        },

        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },

        lastname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },

        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },

        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
        
    }


    /**
     *  @options
     */
    public static $options: object = {
        timestamps: true
    }

}


export default User.init() // need to return User class (for static methods usage)
```

```
// the same with product model
class Product extends Model {
  ... // same as User model but for products
}

Product.init() // need to return Product class
```

I want to avoid two lines:

```
User.init()
export default User
```

And make it one:

```
export default User.init()
```

So, I need that when calling `User.init()` or `Product.init()` or `AnyClass.init()` from classes that extends from Model, the returned type be the type of the class who calls `init` method: `User|Product|AnyClass`

Is important to mention that my Model class is extending from the Sequelize Model class as well, which uses static methods.

So in my controller I use User model like this:

```
const users = User.findAll() // a list of all users
```

---

**You can get the workspace running from gitpod:**

https://gitpod.io/#snapshot/0a676aff-fdf2-4585-b349-53516d0c677e

**Run the server:** `yarn dev` (url path: `/test-seeder`) this is optional

**Run the test** (should pass if all is okay): `yarn test setup`

I need to do those changes

Answer (score 0):

The tip to solve this problem is setting the magic `this` keyword as the 1st argument of static method.

There are 2 use cases with above snippet:

- As I know, `SequelizeModel` is the an abstract class so as you extends it you have to return the correct type of `init` static method which is an instance of a class not a class itself. So the code would look like this:

```js
class Model extends SequelizeModel {
 
  public static init<M extends Model>(this: { new(): M }) { // `M` is an instance
    return new this();
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  baz: number = 1;
}

User.init().baz // result would be an instance of `User`
```

- If you wish to return a different static method returning class itself rather than an instance of it:

```js
class Model extends SequelizeModel {
  
  public static yourMethod<M>(this: M) { // `M` is now just a class
    return this;
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  static baz: number = 1;
}

User.init().baz // result would be class of `User`
```

#### Edit real code

```js
class Model extends SequelizeModel {
  /**
   *  @default options
   */
  public static options: InitOptions = {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: true,
  };

  /**
   *  @custom options
   */
  public static $options: object = {};

  /**
   *  @model definition
   */
  public static attributes: ModelAttributes = {};

  /**
   *  @init the model
   */
  public static init<M extends Model>(this: { new(): M }) {
    return super.init.call(this, Model.attributes, {
      ...Model.options,
      ...Model.$options,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't need to return a new `this` instance.
When I do example 2, I'm getting an error from my super.init.call( this, this.attributes, this.options): `Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ModelStatic<Model<any, any>>'.`

Comment: Currently `init` method defines `this` as `this: ModelStatic<M>` (`type ModelStatic<M extends Model> = { new(): M }`)  which is not compatible with `M`. I would suggest to cast `this` to `any` as a work-around for now: `super.init.call(this as any, this.attributes, this.options) `

Comment: I can't getting work... I will update the post with the entire code version

Comment: I dropped you an updated code for you. Not sure why did you access static members via `this` keyword which is supposed to be class name instead

Comment: Thanks very much but I get: `Property 'findAll' is a static member of type 'Model<any, any>'` when I do `User.findAll()`. In the init method I'm just trying to pass the childs attributes and a merge of the default and custom options to the super init function

Comment: I think is because init is returning a new instance and not the class who calls itself...

Comment: I'm confused what you want to achieve now? Can you post the related code?

Comment: Yes, I tried to post a reduced version of the code but I guess did not result so well. I updated the post.

Comment: I share to you the workspace running from gitpod (log with github): https://gitpod.io/#snapshot/0a676aff-fdf2-4585-b349-53516d0c677e

I updated the post with indications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226519/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-diego-ulloa).

Answer (score 0):

Is an issue not resolved yet: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863